# Xcode Crashes when making any changes to a XIB

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am very new to Xcode and I am starting with some tutorials I found online. There is one screen I am trying to edit and when I change anything about the XIB (IE: even relocate a label), XCode crashes with the following error. What can be causing this?

Thank you!!

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
```

Application Specific Information:

```
ProductBuildVersion: 5A3005
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-4514/Framework/Document/IBDocument.m:2551
Details:  An instance of IBUILabel with object ID 6 did not archive its child (IBUITextField) with an object of ID 7.
Object:   <IBCocoaTouchDocument: 0x7fbddf2e4b70>
Method:   -documentArchiver:didArchiveObject:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fbdd9408530>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
```

Comment: This is 100% repeatable - if I change anything on the XIB it crashes Xcode completely. If I open the XIB up in Text Wrangler and change something (such as the text of the label) it seems to work OK... (but VERY difficult to make any substantial changes!).

Comment: Did you try turning it off and on again? i.e. restart your mac? Or alternatively, revert to a known working version of the XIB file. You do have version control don't you?

Comment: Definitely try a full shut down, restart. Also, were the .xib's you are changing created using the same version of xcode you are now using?

Comment: I tried a full reboot and tried doing a project "clean" without any luck. Is there anyway to tell which version the XIB was made in? I am running the latest on Mavericks but the documentation for the tutorials don't mention how they were made...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out! Turns out that if I use my OLD Mac running Lion, Xcode can edit the XIB without an issue. I can then save it to my new Mac and it works fine in the new project!!